# Secondary LUKS physical volume won't automount

Tags: fedora, fstab, luks, crypttab

I've got a second hard drive in my laptop. However, it only mounts itself when I load the GUI and click on the device in Nemo. What I'd like is for it to automount on boot.

```
sudo lsblk -f
NAME                                          FSTYPE      LABEL       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
    sdb                                                                                                          
    ├─sdb2                                        ntfs        BIOS_RVY    F61C92C71C9281F3                       
    └─sdb1                                        crypto_LUKS             3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5   
      └─luks-3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5 ext4                    32c29f17-28fd-4288-8680-2fc62027586a   /run/media/bill/32c29f17-28fd-4288-8680-2fc62027586a
    sr0                                                                                                          
    sda                                                                                                          
    ├─sda4                                        ntfs        WinRE tools 0CDA8AEEDA8AD2FE                       
    ├─sda2                                                                                                       
    ├─sda5                                        crypto_LUKS             28c449da-d8ba-42be-8a4e-17822270b7bd   
    │ └─luks-28c449da-d8ba-42be-8a4e-17822270b7bd LVM2_member             LQR013-0T1K-E5QL-8sVa-94rN-C8cE-Agfbtn 
    │   ├─fedora-root                             ext4                    047ddca4-cfb8-4307-9c86-a8de31c0bc68   /
    │   ├─fedora-swap                             swap                    18e032b2-eb2c-485c-97ce-b500c675dfda   [SWAP]
    │   └─fedora-home                             ext4                    19caa2b4-d5a3-4c0d-bd76-c11ec303dd0c   /home
    ├─sda3                                        ext4                    f11b0191-49b9-41c2-a8f2-f26851442b17   /boot
    └─sda1                                        vfat        SYSTEM      1288-7285                              /boot/efi
```

(Ignore the NTFS partitions, these are the recovery partitions from the original OEM WIndows setup, just in case I ever want to restore it to factory.)

My fstab is:

```
/dev/mapper/fedora-root /                       ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 1 1
UUID=f11b0191-49b9-41c2-a8f2-f26851442b17 /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=1288-7285          /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-home /home                   ext4    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 1 2
/dev/mapper/fedora-swap swap                    swap    defaults,x-systemd.device-timeout=0 0 0
/extraswap  none    swap    sw  0   0
```

and crypttab is

```
luks-28c449da-d8ba-42be-8a4e-17822270b7bd UUID=28c449da-d8ba-42be-8a4e-17822270b7bd none discard 
luks-3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5 UUID=3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5 none luks
```

Both drives are encrypted with the same passphrase, and I only have to enter it once during boot. I tried adding the following to fstab

```
/dev/mapper/luks-3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5 /run/media/bill/32c29f17-28fd-4288-8680-2fc62027586a ext4 defaults 0 2
```

However, it got an error on boot. My guess is that it's something to do with LVM and I need to add a reference in there?

Comment: Try to use a different mount point. `/var/run` shouldn't be used for static mounts. Create a directory beneath `/mnt` by `mkdir -p /mnt/mydisk` and replace `/run/media/bill/32c29f17-28fd-4288-8680-2fc62027586a` by `/mnt/mydisk` in the `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Thomas points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/344237/secondary-luks-physical-volume-wont-automount#comment609203_344237), the following worked:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/data
```

Then in `fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/luks-3df2999e-9b64-46ec-b634-7986877c57f5 /mnt/data ext4 defaults 0 2
```